# Why doesn't my Discord bot add a role or respond with any errors?

Tags: python, discord.py

Code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    elif message.content.startswith(commandPrefix + 'afk'):
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="afk")
        try:
            await Member.add_roles(role)
            await message.channel.send('*' + str(message.author) + ' is now AFK.*')
        except discord.Forbidden:
            await client.send_message("FIREBOT \n Something went wrong! \n [ERR AFKForbidden]")
            print("FIREBOT \n Something went wrong! \n [ERR AFKForbidden] \n ====================")
```

Returns:
*Fire bot: MrHallway0#4864 is now AFK.* but **doesn't** add the role `afk`. I have tried using `client.add_role` although that didn't work either.

I am sorry I am new to making Discord bots with `discord.py`.

Comment: You need to assign the role to `message.author`. You are using `Member` but did not define that in your code.

Comment: You're calling add_roles method from the Member class itself, which doesn't make sense. You should address the actual member, i.e. message.author

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to `add_roles` to a member (`discord.Member`) you must use a a member like `message.author` not the class `Member`

```py
# use the command/message author
await message.author.add_roles(role)

# or get another member
member = message.guild.get_member(1234) # 1234 must be a valid user id
await member.add_roles(role)
```

There is no error message because you "block it" with the `try: except:` block, and `discord.Forbidden` is not the error you would geld in line `await Member.add_roles(role)`
With `except Exception as e:` you can except every other error, `e` is just a variable name

```py
try:
    pass # do stuff here
except discord.Forbidden:
    print(f"FIREBOT\n Something went wrong!\n [ ERR AFKForbidden ] \n====================")
except Exception as e: # every other error
    print(f"FIREBOT\n Something went wrong!\n [ {e} ] \n====================")
```

You can use `f-strings` to format ansers more easily. Just add a `f` in front of a string (`f'message'`), you can then insert variables inside `{}` like `f'hello {name}'`

```py
>>> name = 'Guddi'
>>> print(f'Hello {name}!')
Hello Guddi!
```

in your case:

```py
# change this
await message.channel.send('*' + str(message.author) + ' is now AFK.*')
#to this
await message.channel.send(f'* {message.author} is now AFK.*')
#                          ^
```

Comment: This work but when ever I call `ctx` it returns as undefined. Do you know why this would be?

Comment: `ctx` is a [`command.Context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) type, it only works in "real" [`commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#commands) with [`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot) instead of [`discord.Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client)

Comment: if you use the [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message) event there is just the [`message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message), not the `ctx`